# CSS transition only works one way and the element will only revert without transition

Tags: css, animation

i'm trying to have my main element to start from a state with transform and when you hover over it will transform with a transition. however, when you unhover it, the element transforms back to it's original state without doing a transition. if i put transition in the main as well then it would transform when the page loads with a transition. i want it to not change in the beginnning. any help would do.

```
main {
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    transform:perspective(1500px) rotateX(50deg);
    transition:transform 2s;
}

main:hover {
    transition:transform 2s;
    transform:perspective(0px) rotateX(0deg);
}
```

Comment: Put `transition:transform 2s;` inside `main`.

Comment: adding transition inside main as well makes the main transform when the page refreshes, however i want it to transform without transition in the beginning. how should i do that?

Comment: You can remove the `transition` from the `:hover` state. You don't need it. Is there another CSS rule applying a transform to your main? Check this fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/wsoyzhtj/ There is no transition on page refresh.

Comment: @Shinji See my "answer". Your posted example code does not exhibit the problem you are describing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `transition: transform 2s;` from `main:hover`, and put it inside `main`.

```css
.main {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  transition: transform 2s;
  transform: perspective(1500px) rotateX(50deg);
}

.main:hover {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="main"></div>
```

Comment: i tried my code in codepen and it works, however it does not work in chrome. do you know why?

Comment: It should work. I tried this code on Chrome and Firefox, it works. Also please note that there is `.` before main and main:hover in my answer. Remove them in your code. Because you are targeting `main` element, not `main` class in your code.  @Shinji

Answer (score 1):

Including it in the main normal state will fix this:

```
main {
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    -webkit-transform:perspective(1500px) rotateX(50deg);
            transform:perspective(1500px) rotateX(50deg);
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 2s;
    transition:-webkit-transform 2s;
    -o-transition:transform 2s;
    transition:transform 2s;
    transition:transform 2s, -webkit-transform 2s;
    background: red;
}

main:hover {
    -webkit-transform:perspective(0px) rotateX(0deg);
            transform:perspective(0px) rotateX(0deg);
}
```

View [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/89724kab/).

Without transition on initial hover, set it to none for normal state:

```
main {
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    -webkit-transform:perspective(1500px) rotateX(50deg);
            transform:perspective(1500px) rotateX(50deg);
    background: red;

    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 2s;

    transition:-webkit-transform 2s;

    -o-transition:transform 2s;

    transition:transform 2s;

    transition:transform 2s, -webkit-transform 2s;
}

main:hover {
    -webkit-transform:perspective(0px) rotateX(0deg);
            transform:perspective(0px) rotateX(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -o-transition: none;
    transition: none;
}
```

View [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/89724kab/1/).

Answer (score 1):

The example you give in the opening post does not exhibit the problem you are referring to of applying the transition animation on page reload.

For example:

```css
.main {
    background: #DDD;
    width: 100px;
    height: 80px;
    transition: transform 2s;
    transform: perspective(1500px) rotateX(50deg);
}

.main:hover {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="main"></div>
```

This is essentially identical to your example and shows the desired outcome. So you should double check if there are other transitions that you may misinterpret, or other events that cause the hover style to become active.

In the current state, this question cannot be answered.